# Replace every occurence of a character except the last one in every line

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to replace occurrences of "|" **EXCEPT** the last one in every line of a file with a space using **sed only**.  I want to avoid doing this:

```
 sed -e "s/[|]/ /1" -e "s/[|]/ /1" -e "s/[|]/ /1" -e "s/[|]/ /1" -e "s/[|]/ /1"  -e "s/[|]/ /1" -e "s/[|]/ /1" mydata.txt
```

File input:

```
FLD1     |SFK TK |FLD2   |FLD4 |FLD5 |-          |20200515 |NNNN |406   RCO 301
FLD1     |SFK TK |FLD2   |FLD4 |FLD5 |-          |20200515 |NNNN |0
FLD1     |SFK TK |FLD2   |FLD4 |FLD5 |-          |20200515 |NNNN |0
```

File output:

```
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN |406   RCO 301
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN |0
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN |0
```

Comment: What if there is only one `|` on the line? So the first one will also be the last one. Should that be removed or left alone?

Comment: @terdon, never occurred to me, a good point, but a single "|" would never be the case for my input file.

Comment: Are the number of pipe delimited fields fixed? If yes, `sed 'y/|/\n/;s/\n/|/8;y/\n/ /' file` can be used.

Comment: If the number of `|` is fixed, a nicely chosen combination of `cut` and `paste` would probably do it.

Answer (score 20):

```
sed ':a;/[|].*[|]/s/[|]/ /;ta' file
```

- `/[|].*[|]/`: If line has two pipes,
- `s/[|]/ /`: Substitute the first with a space.
- `ta`: If a substitution was made, go back to `:a`.

Output:

```
$ sed ':a;/[|].*[|]/s/[|]/ /;ta' file
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN |406   RCO 301
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN |0
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN |0
```

As @steeldriver has remarked, you can use simply `|` instead of `[|]` in a basic regular expression (BRE), as is the case above. If you add the `-E` flag to sed, extended regular expression (ERE) is enabled and then you need to write `[|]` or `\|`.

---

Just for completeness, [POSIX sed specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03) says that "Editing commands other than **{...}, a, b, c, i, r, t, w, :,** and **#** can be followed by a semicolon". Then, a compliant alternative to the above is:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '/[|].*[|]/s/[|]/ /;t a' file
```

Comment: Slightly different, but very similar: `sed -e ':again' -e 's/|\(.*\)|/ \1|/' -e 't again' file` (also POSIX, as you need a newline after a label ordinarily).

Comment: The POSIX spec also indicates that the `t` command verb shall be separated from its argument by a single space: `t a` rather than `ta`

Answer (score 10):

A different approach from [Quasímodo's explicit loop in `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587299/116858):

```
$ sed 'h; s/.*|//; x; s/|[^|]*$//; y/|/ /; G; y/\n/|/' file
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN |406   RCO 301
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN |0
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN |0
```

For each line, this saves the line in the hold space with `h` and then removes everything on the line up to and including the last `|`.  It then swaps in the original copy of the line and removes the last `|` and everything after it.

The pattern space now contains the original first portion of the line, and the hold space contains the last portion of the line.

The first `y///` command replaces all remaining `|` with spaces.  `G` appends the hold space to the end of the pattern space with a newline character in-between.  The second `y///` command transforms that newline character to a `|`, and we're done.

Doing a limited (fixed) number of `s///` substitutions and using the faster `y///` command when possible means that this runs quicker than the explicit loop variation (~2.3 seconds on 50 MiB data, compared to ~7.8 seconds on the same data with the loop, using GNU `sed` on my machine).

Interestingly, using a back reference in the explicit loop variation, like both me and Isaac did, slows it down even more (~33s with [Isaac's variation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587304/116858), and ~29s with mine ([in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587297/replace-every-occurence-of-a-character-except-the-last-one-in-every-line/587302#comment1093906_587299)), on the same data set and under the same conditions as above).

---

Using `awk`, this *almost* replaces all `|` delimiters except the last one by a space. "Almost" since it *inserts* a space before the last `|`.

```
$ awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS = " " } { $NF = "|" $NF; print }' file
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN  |406   RCO 301
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN  |0
FLD1      SFK TK  FLD2    FLD4  FLD5  -           20200515  NNNN  |0
```

It reads each line as a set of `|`-delimited fields, prepends a `|` character to the start of the last field, and prints the resulting record with spaces for field delimiters.

With taking the default behavior of `awk` into account (space is the default output field delimiter, and the input field delimiter is available as `FS`):

```
awk -F '|' '{ $NF = FS $NF; print }' file
```

or, slightly shorter, courtesy of @Isaac,

```
awk -F '|' '{ $NF = FS $NF }; 1' file
```

Answer (score 8):

Using Perl you could run something along the lines of

```
perl -pe 's/\|(?=.*\|)/ /g'     ex
```

where:

- `perl -pe` action  -- executes action and print
- `\|(?=.*\|)` is a regular expression that matches `|` with a not consumed lookeahed `(?=.*|)` containing another `|`

Answer (score 5):

Posixly:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '/|\(.*|\)/s// \1/;ta' file
```

- `-e ':a'` define a label (`a`) to jump.
- `-e '`    start another script section.
- `/|\(.*|\)/` one regex to match two `|`, everything in the middle
              and to capture all in between and the last `|`.
- `s// \1/`   replace everyting matched above with what was captured.
- `;ta`       loop again.
- `' file`    on the filename given.

---

To measure the speed of all the options (from faster to slower) you can use:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
TIMEFORMAT='run : %lR sec'

read -d '' str <<\END
FLD1     |SFK TK |FLD2   |FLD4 |FLD5 |-          |20200515 |NNNN |406   RCO 301
FLD1     |SFK TK |FLD2   |FLD4 |FLD5 |-          |20200515 |NNNN |0
FLD1     |SFK TK |FLD2   |FLD4 |FLD5 |-          |20200515 |NNNN |0'
END

n=${1:-100}; printf "$str"'%.0s\n' $(seq "$n") > file

time perl -pe 's/\|(?=.*\|)/ /g' file >/dev/null
time sed -E ':a;/\|.{1,}\|/s/\|/ /1;ta' file >/dev/null
time sed 'h; s/.*|//; x; s/|[^|]*$//; y/|/ /; G; y/\n/|/' file >/dev/null
time sed 's/\(.*\)|/\1\x00/;y/|/ /;s/\x00/|/1' file >/dev/null
time sed 's/\(.*\)|/\1\n/;y/|/ /;s/\n/|/1' file >/dev/null
```

To be used as:

```
$ ./testbash.sh 235000
run    : 0m07.676s sec
run    : 0m17.753s sec
run    : 0m22.074s sec
run    : 0m24.036s sec
run    : 0m24.047s sec
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of alternatives you can use.

```
$ sed -e '
   s/|[^|]*$/\n&/
   s/\n|/\n/
   y/\n|/| /
' file

$ perl -pe 's/\|/ / until tr/|/|/ == 1' file

$ perl -pe 'my $k=tr/|/|/; s/\|/ / while $k-->1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

What about cheating this way ? No one said we needed just one `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/\|([^|]+)$/##\1/' | sed 's/|/ /g' | sed 's/##/|/'
```

Here, I used `##` as a placeholder, replace only the last `|` of the line with it, replace all the other `|`, and then put back the last one. Just make sure you have no `##` in your input.

Comment: This is functionally the same as [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/587297/80216#587571), except mine replaces the last `|` with a newline, which cannot possibly occur within a line (so you don't need to include a disclaimer).  Note that you can have multiple `sed` *commands* within a single `sed` *process* / *invocation.*  It's very rare to need to pipe one `sed` process into another, let alone two others.

Answer (score 1):

Without a loop:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)|/\1\
/; s/|/ /g; s/\
/|/'
```

- Replace the last vertical bar in each line with a newline. 
  (This may be inserted into the pattern space,
  but is guaranteed not to be there initially.)
- Replace all remaining vertical bars with spaces.
- Replace the newline (inserted with the first command)
  with a vertical bar.

Comment: That is exactly the last approach (the slowest) in my answer, sorry. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If number of fields is always the same, `cut` +`tr` & `paste` with a shell that supports `<()`:

```
paste -d\| <(cut -d\| -f1-8 file | tr \| ' ') <(cut -d\| -f9 file)
```

Or with GNU `cut`&`paste`:

```
paste -d\| <(cut -d\| --output-delimiter=' ' -f1-8 file) <(cut -d\| -f9 file)
```