# sed conditional branch "t" keeps branching even when the last substitution is unsuccessful

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following sed expressions:

```bash
echo 'abcabcabc' | sed -n ':-A s/a/x/1; s/a/&/2;t-A; p'
```

Which supposedly should replace every occurrence of `'a'` with `'x'` except the last one.
So, the expected output is this:

```
xbcxbcabc
```

but the actual ouput is this:

```
xbcxbcxbc
```

Which replaces all `'a'` with `'x'`

I know there have been already similar questions like this, like  [Replace every occurence of a character except the last one in every line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587297/replace-every-occurence-of-a-character-except-the-last-one-in-every-line)

But I'm trying a different approach here using sed conditional branch.

Let me break down my sed expressions with my own understanding

so first here's the sed expressions again:

```bash
echo 'abcabcabc' | sed -n ':-A s/a/x/1; s/a/&/2;t-A; p'
```

sed pulls this `abcabcabc` into the pattern space

then set a label `:-A`

then `s/a/x/1;` replace the first occurence of `'a'` with `'x'`. Now the pattern space contains this `xbcabcabc`

`s/a/&/2;` checks if the pattern space contains two `'a'`, which it does, so it replaces the two `'a'` with themselves `&`. So the pattern space still contains this `xbcabcabc`

`t-A` since the most recent subtitution is successful, jump back to label `-A`

starting from label `-A` it does this again `s/a/x/1;` which turns the content of pattern space from this `xbcabcabc` to this `xbcxbcabc`

`s/a/&/2` it checks if there are two `'a'` again. This time the pattern space contains this `xbcxbcabc` which does not have two `'a'` so the substitution is unsuccessful.

`t-A` since the most recent subtitution is **unsuccessful**, it should not jump back to label `-A` but instead proceed with `p` which prints whatever in the pattern space which is this `xbcxbcabc` then exit.
But instead, even when the subtitution is **unsuccessful** it jumps back to label `-A` again and replaces the remaining `'a'` with `'x'`. so it ends up with this `xbcxbcxbc`

if I insert `l` between expressions:

```bash
 echo 'abcabcabc' | sed -n ':-A s/a/x/1;  l; s/a/&/2;t-A; p'
```

output:

```
xbcabcabc$
xbcxbcabc$
xbcxbcxbc$
xbcxbcxbc$
xbcxbcxbc
```

we can see it branches again even when the pattern space contains this `xbcxbcabc`

So, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `s/a/&/2` would replace the 2nd `a` with itself.  It would not replace two `a`.  Likewise, `s/a/x/1` is always the same as `s/a/x/` (it replaces the 1st `a` with `x`).  This is irrelevant to the question but still a misconception that may come back to bite you in some other context.

The `t` command branches if there has been a successful substitution since the last input line was read unless another `t` command has been triggered since then, according to the GNU `sed` manual:

> `t label`
> If a `s///` has done a successful substitution since the last
> input line was read and since the last `t` or `T` command, then
> branch to `label`; if `label` is omitted, branch to end of script.

[The POSIX specification for the same command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) agrees with this:

> `[2addr]t [label]`
> Test. Branch to the `:` command verb bearing the `label` if any substitutions have been made since the most recent reading of an input line or execution of a `t`. If `label` is not specified, branch to the end of the script.

So, to summarise: If any `s` command is successful for your single line of input, since the most recent `t` command, the `t` command will always branch to the given label.

Your data is first transformed into `xbcabcabc`, then to `xbcxbcabc`.  When arriving at this result, the initial `s` command for the iteration successfully replaced the first `a` with `x`, so the `t` command branches, giving you `xbcxbcxbc`.

A way to fix this is to insert an extra `t` command and a dummy label:

```bash
echo abcabcabc |
sed -e :A -e 's/a/x/'  -e tB \
    -e :B -e 's/a/&/2' -e tA
```

The execution of `tB` "resets the successful-flag" of that first `s` command.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just keep it clear and simple and use awk instead? e.g. with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ echo 'abcabcabc' |
    awk '{match($0,/(.*)(a.*)/,t); gsub(/a/,"x",t[1]); print t[1] t[2]}'
xbcxbcabc
```

or with any awk:

```
$ echo 'abcabcabc' |
    awk '{match($0,/.*a/); t=substr($0,1,RLENGTH-1); gsub(/a/,"x",t); print t substr($0,RLENGTH)}'
xbcxbcabc
```

Any time you find yourself considering using sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) just be aware there's almost certainly a clearer, simpler, more efficient, more robust, and/or more portable solution using awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the text, replace from 2 to end and reverse again.

```
$ echo 'abcabcabc' | rev | sed 's/a/x/2g' | rev
xbcxbcabc
```

No need for labeling and looping in this simple case unless you are doing some exercise in recursive features of sed.